# 500 Internal Server Error while trying to Rewrite URL in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need your help in creating dynamic URL for SEO gains.. I tried to implement the following .htaccess on my present URL. But I got an **500 Internal Server Error**

please where could the problem be?
Thanks

**Link**

```
http://127.0.0.1/index.php?id=1
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$1
```

**Apache Error Log**

> Invalid Command 'RewriteEngine',     perhaps misspelled or defined by a      module not included in the server configuration

Comment: The rule looks fine. Check your server log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` on Linux) - there will be an entry since it's a 500 error. Probably some configuration thing.

Comment: Oh wait, you have `a-Z` and `A-z` - which is weird. put `a-zA-Z`

Comment: It would also help if you posted the URL that is being rewritten, not just what the result should be

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder what does _defined by a module not included in the server configuration_ mean?

Comment: The rewritelog says mod_rewrite is not enabled/installed. Rule seems to look fine, although you might need `Option -Multiviews` to get it working properly.

Comment: @gerben .. Can you please explain how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your rule with

```
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

`a-Z` doesn't work the way one might think it does, and `A-z` is just weird. That's what's throwing the error.

Also, adding the `[L]` flag prevents further rewriting.

Comment: OK then you need to look into installing and enabling `mod_rewrite` for Apache. It should be as simple as `sudo a2enmod mod_rewrite`.

Comment: And then add `AllowOverride All` in the Directory configuration of your virtual host conf file.

Comment: But that should not force a 500 AFIK. +1 for pointing so fast my mistakes ;-)

Comment: Oh yeah - that won't be a 500, but the rule would never match :) No problem. No malice intended :)

Comment: Dude chill with the downvote - OP hadn't pasted the error log at first! When answering .htaccess questions I typically assume they've installed, loaded and enabled that module unless something indicates otherwise. Plus the mistake I pointed out is valid - his rule wouldn't have worked even if he had enabled mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [mod rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: No there's no loop here - his rule only replaces `index` if there is a slash following it.

Comment: Also, you probably meant `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REMOTE_HOST}` :)

Comment: I rewrote my answer compleatly.

Comment: May be you just need to _load_ it.

Comment: Loading is a part of the Installation isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily - just enable it and you should be good to go.